# Is this QML binding bug or I missed something?

Tags: qt, qml

There are two QML files as following, the expected behavior is that the values of A's `isSunny` and B's `isCloudyInA` are always opposite, and A's `isSunny` is binding to `A._innerObjA.isInnerSunny`, and `B._innerItemB.isCloudyInA` is binding to `A.isSunny` in loader's `onLoaded` signal.

Those code works fine over thousands of times, but just once, it doesn't work as expected: the value of `isCloudyInA` is always `false`, but `A.isSunny` changes between `true` and `false` as normal.

This situation happened just once in that run cycle (means during the whole life cycle of the application after that startup), the problem is gone after restarting the program and we cannot reproduce it again.

- We are using Qt 5.15.
- `B._innerItemB.isCloudyInA` is used in UI, when the issue happened, UI behaves as the value of `B._innerItemB.isCloudyInA` is always `false`, which matches the log.
- When the issue happened, it had following logs, we can see the log of " B onIsCloudyInAChanged: " is missing after `line 4`.

```
A onIsInnerSunnyChanged: true
B onIsCloudyInAChanged: true
A.qml loaded!
B onIsCloudyInAChanged: false // line 4
A onIsInnerSunnyChanged: false
A onIsInnerSunnyChanged: true
A onIsInnerSunnyChanged: false
```

```
// A.qml
Item {
    id: root

    property bool isSunny: true

    QtObject {
        id: _innerObjA

        readonly property bool isInnerSunny: <bool expression>  // a boolen expression that may change over time

        onIsInnerSunnyChanged: {
            console.log("A onIsInnerSunnyChanged: " + _innerObjA.isInnerSunny);
        }

        Binding {   // BindingA
           target: root
           property: "isSunny"
           when: true
           delayed: true
           value: _innerObjA.isInnerSunny
        }
    }
}
```

```
// B.qml
Item {
    id: root

    Loader {
        id: _loader

        source: Qt.resolvedUrl("./A.qml")
        asynchronous: true
        active: true

        onLoaded: {
            _innerItemB.isCloudyInA = Qt.binding(() => !item.isSunny); // BindingB
            console.log("A.qml loaded!");
        }
    }

    QtObject {
        id: _innerItemB
        property bool isCloudyInA: true // used on UI
        onIsCloudyInAChanged: {
            console.log("B onIsCloudyInAChanged: " + isCloudyInA)
        }
    }
}
```

Q: based on those logs, it looks like the binding is broken(but it's not clear the broken happens on BindingA or BindingB). Can we consider it's a bug of Qt/QML binding? Is there any other possible reason that can cause this issue?

We are not sure if it's a bug of QML binding or we missed something.

Comment: What is `QObject`? Also, you have one extra closed bracket in your `B.qml`. Does your code even work?

Comment: Just updated the syntax error in code, sorry for the confusion. Please ignore those typo because real code doesn't have such problem. Thanks.

Comment: Another issue is that `QtObject` doesn't have any default property, so `Binding` can't be used inside it. Aside from this, your code works fine. I changed the `isInnerSunny` property using a `Timer` with a 1000 ms interval, and there were no binding breaks.

Comment: @smr, thank you for your try, yes it works generally, the strange point is that the "broken binding" issue happened just one time during thousands times of running. In that time, both UI behavior and logging show that it's kind of binding is broken, that's why we are considering it might be a bug of QML/QT. 
Btw, according to the documentation about binding with "delayed" property, it will need to create a extra "proxy" to handle that.

Comment: So I may not be able to help since I couldn't reproduce it after several tries. The current code looks okay to me, and I don't think the `delayed` property would cause any problems. However, I suggest that you try a different approach based on your main source code. I can't provide many suggestions since this is not your main source code, but perhaps trying to use `Connections` instead of binding would make a difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply @smr. It's hard to say this is a bug directly. At the moment we are using `Qt.callLater()` instead of the `Binding{ delayed: xxx}` to achieve the same result.

Comment: Be aware that if `Qt.callLater` is called multiple times in quick succession with the same function as its first argument, that function will be called only once. https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-qt.html#callLater-method